# Библиотека совместимости фрагментов

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-support-library

Вопрос уточняющий. Фрагменты появились в 3й версии Андроид API 11, ориентируюсь я на пользователей начиная с API 15 и выше. Значит не нужно использовать `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`? Эта либа для поддержки фрагментов в версиях ниже 3, так же ведь?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если хотите использовать все современные возможности фрагментов, исправления и максимально одинаковое поведение на разных версиях андройда, то лучше использовать фрагменты и библиотеки поддержки. Смысл использовать родные фрагменты есть, только если у вас довольно маленькое приложение и вы хотите сделать его макимально маленьким). Нынче даже сама Android Studio по умолчанию при создании нового проекта с активити и фрагментами использует таковые из сапорт либы.

Answer (score 2):

Да всё верно. Получается так, что если вы хотите использовать фрагменты и покрывать устройства версии ниже чем API11, то необходимо использовать android.support.v4.app.Fragment.

Если в этом нет нужды, используйте android.app.Fragment

Comment: Тут есть такой нюанс, что часто в дублирующие  классы библиотек поддержки вносятся фиксы, исправляющие опредленные проблемы или  дополнения, в то время, как для основного API это не делается. Так в support.v4.Fragment последние изменения вносились в июле 2016 (и делались довольно регулярно до этого), в то время как в основном API [изменений в классе Fragment](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/24/changes.html) похоже вообще не было, хотя все чейнджлоги мне проверять лень. Где то мне встречалась рекомендация использовать классы из библиотек поддержки, так как они более актуальные

Comment: есть такой нюанс и не только он один - это можно привязать в целом к подключаемым библиотекам. И бывает такое, что вначале появляется в одной а потом в другой, где-то метод deprc а в другой вроде нет, уже не говоря уже о доках и тд - больная тема. 

Что касается фрагментов как пример такое было FragmentPagerAdapter, и ряд методов внутри.