# Нужно ли делать импорт библиотеки поддержки везде где это возможно?

Tags: java, android

Раньше как то не задумывался, что это такое библиотека поддержки. Сейчас немного почитал и понял, что она есть нескольких версий и включает в себя различный набор возможностей. Основная идея в том, чтоб сделать доступными на старых версиях возможности новых.

Так вот от сюда и появился вопрос , зачем мне допустим использовать вот такой импорт

```
import android.app.DialogFragment;
```

Когда есть вот такой в библиотеке поддержки

```
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
```

Нужно ли везде ее использовать или есть противопоказания?

Comment: Я бы закрыл [на этот вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/554449/177345), но может еще кто то хочет высказаться .. Ответ такой, что классы библиотеки поддержки, дублирующие классы из API, предпочтительнее этих классов из API, так как более актуальные. [Мое мнение](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554449/%d0%91%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2#comment715362_554455), если оно кому то интересно.

Comment: @pavlofff спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-моему мнению – да, нужно использовать библиотеки поддержки везде, где это возможно. Мотивация проста – при добавлении нового функционала, этот функционал добавляется и в библиотеки поддержки. Таким образом, чтобы использовать новые возможности в своем приложении – Вам будет достаточно обновить версию библиотеки поддержки.

**Приведу пример:**

Имеется приложение с `minSdkVersion="16"`, в котором используется системная реализация фрагментов. В какой-то момент времени возникла необходимость использовать в этом приложении вложенные фрагменты, поддержку которых [добавили в API level 17](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments). В данной реализации приложения, Вы не сможете использовать эти самые вложенные фрагменты на всех устройствах, которые поддерживаются приложением (в соответствии с заданным `minSdkVersion`).

В этой же ситуации, но при использовании фрагментов из библиотеки поддержки, Вы просто обновите ее и сможете использовать новый функционал на всех поддерживаемых устройствах.

Comment: @ metalurgus что скажите?

Comment: как по мне очень правильная идея

Comment: А я лично не согласен. По той причине, что когда новый функционал добавляют в библиотеку поддержки, то чтобы его использовать, все равно придется переписывать импорты с `com.android.*` на `com.android.support.*`, т. к. раньше этот функционал не был доступен в support библиотеке, а только в определенной версии android

Answer (score 2):

ведь очевидно, что `android.app.DialogFragment` был добавлен в API 11, и если вы хотите использовать `DialogFragment` до 11 версии, то вам нужно использовать `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment` везде.

Support библиотека работает следующим образом:

Если версия 11 или больше, то используется обычный `android.app.DialogFragment`, а если меньше - при помощи набора костылей создается подобие `android.app.DialogFragment`.

Подобным образом работает любой компонент support библиотеки

Comment: То есть совершенно не принципиально использовать ее если нет необходимости?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, да, точно. Главное - правильно рассчитайте, на каких API вы хотите чтобы работало ваше прилодение