# В чем отличие support.v4.fragment от app.fragment

Tags: java, android

Интересует отличие в плане кода support.v4.fragment от app.fragment
Они же подключаются по другому?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/554449/177345

Answer (score 2):

Это одно и то же, за одним исключением:

Есть `SupportLibrary`, которая поддерживает функционал андроид для более старых версий. Иначе говоря, `support.v4.fragment` поддерживается с API 4, вплоть до последней.

а `app.fragment` это API 11 и выше. Если вы используете `support.v4.fragment`, то и `fragmentManager` тоже должен быть `support` - иначе на уровне семантики будет выводиться ошибка.

Резюмирую - разница в поддержке старых версий.

Comment: Прежде чем писать ответ, посмотрите документацию. app.fragment  не с 5 версии андроида доступен. он доступен с API11

Comment: @pavel163 разве я не указал 11 api сказав, что точно не помню, с 2.0 или 3.0?Да, саппорт с 4 поддержки, но фрагменты с 11 - что и было указано. В чем проблема?

Comment: Вы написали:  "а app.fragment это 5.0 и выше".

Comment: В чем отличие?
У меня сейчас все фрагменты построены на v4 , мне надо их переписать на app.Fragment

Comment: Если вы поддерживаете API меньше чем 11 то не надо переписывать. Если у вас API больше чем 11 то можно переписать, можно оставить. На данный момент вы тянете больше классов и методов из библиотеки. Сейчас Support library можно разбить на мелкие части. И если бы вы использовали app.fragment то можно было не подключать к проекту support.v4.fragment. От этого у вас бы уменьшилось количество методов и вес приложения.